# AccessViolationException on ToolTip that faults COMCTL32.dll - .NET 4.0

Tags: winforms, windows-7, .net-4.0, tooltip

We are having an issue with our Windows forms application where it is terminating due to an unhandled exception of type AccessViolationException that the stack trace is indicating occurs within the ToolTip control.

The error occurs at different times in the application, and we are currently not able to reliably reproduce it.
At this stage it is occurring only in production on Windows 7 and only for some users, but not others – even amongst users that use the application in a similar way.
It appears to be machine related and so we have done things like ensure the graphics driver is up to date.

In the event log, there are always 2 different errors logged, one relating to our application:

```
Application: <Application>.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip+ToolTipNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at <Company>.Windows.Forms.<Application>.Startup.Main(System.String[])
```

And one relating to comctl32.dll:

```
Faulting application name: <Application>.exe, version: 7.13.0.2086, time stamp: 0x4ec5e710
Faulting module name: comctl32.dll, version: 5.82.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7b82c
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00043286
Faulting process id: 0xcdc
Faulting application start time: 0x01cca96312446309
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\<Company>\Client\<Application>.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll
Report Id: b425143c-1575-11e1-bccf-6c626d955bf1
```

The first stack trace changes depending on where in the workflow the error occurs, however, the top 9 items on the stack are always the same, the difference is usually a showDialog call that appears in between the Main() method and the RunMessageLoop method. E.g.:

```
Application: <Application>.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip+ToolTipNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at <Company>.Windows.Forms.<Application>.ApplicationForm.<EventSubscribingMethod>(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
   at <Company>.<Application>.<Class1>.RaiseShowResultDialogNowEvent()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at <Company>.Windows.Forms.<Application>.Portal.Startup.Main(System.String[])
```

---- Update ----

I have had a request to include some of the code from Main, I don't want to include all code, but an extract is:

```
 <System.STAThread()> _
    Public Shared Function Main(ByVal args() As String) As Integer
        -- Perform startup validation, setup logging framework, etc
        ...
        Dim appLife as new ApplicationContext(myStartupForm)
        Application.Run(appLife)
        Return 0

    End Function
```

Some additional notes:

- We are using the UI Process Application Block from MS Patterns and Practices
- We do override WndProc in a couple of controls, including CheckBoxComboBox from code project at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/extending_combobox.aspx

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Thanks,

Comment: Show the code in `Main()` please. It looks like you are not calling `Application.Run`.

Comment: Thanks for extra info. `0xc0000005` is a native `NullReferenceException`. As you are saying you are overriding `WndProc` I would likely look there for any null pointers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to MS, there is a known issue with the DataGrid control in certain situations, and the way to avoid this issue is to disable Tooltips for your DataGrid controls.

We will be implementing the change and rolling it out to a pilot group in the next couple of days, I'll post back with success/failure in about a week (unless of course failure happens before then).

The property to set according to MS is `DataGridView.ShowCellToolTips = false;`

This fixed the issue for our application.

To reproduce the issue, we needed to do the following:

- Hover the mouse over a cell in our DataGridView that we knew would show a tooltip
- Alt tab to another application (that will display on top of your application) before the tooltip is shown
- Do not move the mouse
- Alt tab back to our application
- Our application crashes.

Comment: Wow! I was finally able to duplicate my issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/7458915/68936 thanks to your answer! It sucks to have to disable tooltips for all datagridview's, but better than an access violation I suppose. Would you happen to have any reference URL's, or does "According to MS" mean you got the information through private conversations with them? Thanks again for posting your answer.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, I got the answer through the paid support. There was no official KB they could point me to unfortunately. I'm glad this helped you though :-)

Comment: i owe you a lunch.. thanks much for this great answer. it took me to 2 weeks to find this still nothing came up but today because of your courtesy .. i could find it all.  how did u come to know about the same ?

Comment: Relevant issue on github https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/402

Comment: I found more about the tooltip issue here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2892345/system-accessviolationexception-occurs-with-tooltips-in-windows-forms. Including an alternative if you want tool tips on your data grids.

Answer (score 12):

It seems that setting `DataGridView.ShowCellToolTips = false` on `Form.Deactivate` prevents the crash. It can be reset to true on `Form.Activate`.

The tooltip is still shown above the newly focused windows however - but I guess that's better then crashing.

**Or even better:**

The problem only occurs when visual styles are not enabled.

Adding `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` in `main()` before any forms are instantiated solves the problem.

Comment: Confirmed that setting Application.EnableVisualStyles() solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

more details
https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/402

6 years later, solution is unfortunately still "use comctl v6"

Comment: 2021 here and still not resolved, it is a wont fix situation :(