# How to get TextBox's real height?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

My first thought was it would be something like this:

```
int height = textbox.lines.length * lineheight;
```

But it just counts "\xd\n" and lines can be wrapped. Can i get the number of displayed lines or actual height of textbox when everything is visible(the height of text inside)?

Comment: winform wpf? what? You do know that we don't stand next to you, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I show scrollbars on a System.Windows.Forms.TextBox only when the text doesn't fit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73110/how-can-i-show-scrollbars-on-a-system-windows-forms-textbox-only-when-the-text-d)

Comment: Hans Passant, maybe partly it is, but all the answers there besides this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/4147348/1205147 are wrong, and answer by b8adamson looks pretty long and bold to me. I would expect there is a nicer and better workaround :)

Comment: @gdoron I think it's "winform" it's in the Tags...

Comment: @OwaisQureshi. It's there now... It was edited!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if you will ever get a perfect measurement, but this gets close:

```
private int GetTextHeight(TextBox tBox) {
  return TextRenderer.MeasureText(tBox.Text, tBox.Font, tBox.ClientSize,
           TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl).Height;
}
```

The TextBox can be goofy.  With multi-line turned on, if you press a character that causes the word to word-wrap, hitting backspace does not cause it to "un-word-wrap" unless I resize the TextBox.  This was on a Win7-64.  I don't *think* the TextBox control always did that.

Comment: TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl makes it a bit less goofy.

Comment: Yea, thank you, Lars. I already made something up from this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4147348/1205147

Comment: Great! I tried to use Graphics.MeasureText in combination with number of lines (no word-wrap needed in my case). This method calculated slightly too high for each line, so when many lines, my method looked strange with extra space. Your method calculated exactly on the spot! Perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

The function GetLineFromCharIndex() gives you the corrent line index, even if the text is wrapped.

```
int lineCount = textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(int.MaxValue) + 1;
int lineHeightPixel = TextRenderer.MeasureText("X", textBox1.Font).Height;
```