# How to measure height of watermarktextbox in wpf?

Tags: wpf, windows, wpf-controls

This is code of `watermarktextbox`.

```
<xctk:WatermarkTextBox Watermark="Enter First Name" />
```

How would I measure the height of that object?

Comment: i have no idea about that so I asked here @AbhinavSharma

Comment: have you looked into ActualHeight & ActualWidth property?

Comment: No i need height of enter text. @AbhinavSharma

Comment: Please frame your question accordingly then...Look for FontHeight property.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as this :

Assign a name to your component and measure its height using `Height` property in code behind.

**XAML :**

```
<xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="WatermarkTextBox1" Watermark="Enter First Name" />
```

**Codebehind :**

```
var height = WatermarkTextBox1.Height;
```

**EDIT :**
Please use this to get font height. Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9251215/5621607

```
private int GetTextHeight(TextBox tBox) 
{
  return TextRenderer.MeasureText(tBox.Text, tBox.Font, tBox.ClientSize,
           TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl).Height;
}
```

Comment: Thank for replay , `<controls:WatermarkTextBox :Name="txtbox_Commnet"
Height="109"`this code return 109. and actually i need Height of enter text or line of height.

Comment: Updated answer. Please check.

Comment: But watermarkTextbox not using text and font property

Comment: Then try with a textbox if it works. If it works, we can create a custom control derived from textbox since watermark Textbox doesn't support the functionalities you need.

Comment: Error:TextRenderer does not exist current context