# A less memory intensive way to estimate size of a testbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am currently using following code to estimate the size of the textbox:

```
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, pGr As Graphics, sz As SizeF
    For i = 1 To pNumRows
        For j = 1 To pWidth
            sb.Append("W")
        Next
        If pNumRows > 1 Then
            sb.Append(vbCrLf)
        End If
    Next
    pGr = txtTextBox.CreateGraphics
    sz = pGr.MeasureString(sb.ToString, pTextFont, New SizeF(10000, 10000))
    pGr.Dispose()
    txtTextBox.SetSize(CInt(sz.Width), CInt(sz.Height) + 80)
    txtTextBox.Size = New Size(CInt(sz.Width) + 20, CInt(sz.Height) + 100)
```

I was wondering if there is any way to remove the for-loops and do away entirely with the pGr (textbox.CreateGraphics) method and still correctly estimate the size of the textbox. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

If you're wondering why I am (actually the person who wrote the code) is looping through all the 'W', it's because (I think) 'W' has the biggest width and height in the entire character set, so the person (who wrote the code) is trying to guess the maximum area needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I show scrollbars on a System.Windows.Forms.TextBox only when the text doesn't fit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73110/how-can-i-show-scrollbars-on-a-system-windows-forms-textbox-only-when-the-text-d)

Comment: This is in no way related to the scrollbars issue. I am trying to ascertain the maximum size of the textbox given the number of rows and columns. Please take back your downvote so that some other person can help me.

Comment: Did you give Hans method a go and try to adjust it for your purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This eliminates your loops (and replaces with them loops in the framework, hopefully faster ones).  Not sure about performance.

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, pGr As Graphics, sz As SizeF
sb.Append(new String("W", pWidth))

If pNumRows > 1 Then
     sb.Append(new String(vbLf, pWidth)) ' may want to use vbCR instead
End If

pGr = txtTextBox.CreateGraphics
sz = pGr.MeasureString(sb.ToString, pTextFont, New SizeF(10000, 10000))
pGr.Dispose()
txtTextBox.SetSize(CInt(sz.Width), CInt(sz.Height) + 80)
txtTextBox.Size = New Size(CInt(sz.Width) + 20, CInt(sz.Height) + 100)
```